# Where is simple Java project/module template in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

There are many provided projects or module templates in IntelliJ, including JavaEE, Jav Enterprise, etc.

But I can't see any simple project template where I can write a simple `"Hello World"` app.

What should I use in this case?

[image]

Comment: Intellij isn't really designed to write hello world applications - you don't need an IDE for that. You could look into [Maven archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select **Java EE**, then press **Next**, you will see 
[image]
[image]

I am using `IntelliJ 14.0.3 Ultimate`